# Find straight double quotes outside of HTML tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm editing an e-book with a number of straight double quotes interspersed in the text among the curly ones, with no apparent rule. Is there a regular expression that can:

1) find the straight double quotes **outside** of HTML tags, and **outside only**?
2) possibly replace them with the curly ones?

A similar question has been posted, but the answers didn't work for me.

**EDIT**. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>PART II</title>
<link href="../Styles/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<p class="centertop2"><span class="big171">CHAPTER 20</span></p>

<p class="para">“Blah blah blah," said A, "blah blah?” (description) “Blah blah.” To which B replied: "Blah blah."</p>
```

If you look at the dialogue, you'll see curly quotes mixed with straight ones. I'd like to find only the straight quotes in the text, and avoid those in HTML tags. Is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps can you post several problematics samples?

Comment: What language will you be doing this in? Really depends on the regular expression engine.

Comment: **@ hwnd**  I'm editing the book in Calibre, which uses a Python engine. However, it's not the usual 're' module, but a new implementation titled 'regex', as explained here: [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

Comment: Is the problem maybe even worse because there are *two* kinds of curly double quotes? “”

Comment: **@ Jasper**  The replace part is less important, the find part is crucial.